# Can Ripple Unique Node Lists (of validators) be weighted?

Tags: ripple, doublespend, nodes

My understanding is that in order to limit / remove the risk of collusion in the Ripple system the consensus mechanism relies on local Unique Node Lists (UNLs) specific to each node in the network (but potentially provided to the node by a gateway or other third party).

My question is whether these UNLs can be assigned discretionary weights by the user (e.g. if the list comprises A,B,C nodes, can they be weighted 4/6, 1/6, 1/6 respectively)?

If not, would it be possible to include a node several times on the list to achieve such weighting, or do they have to be 'unique' as 'Unique NL' seems to suggest..

(Weighting might be interesting if a large amount of trust is ascribed to one or more particular nodes..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have information from the #ripple IRC channel that 'unique' nodes are weighted equally in the current implementation.